# CSS / SCSS - Access child of child element with unknown child type

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

If I have some html like this, with only a class applied to the root. I want to access all `<i>` tags which are located deeper in the html.

some example html:

```
<div class="some-class">
  <div> <!-- unknown type - could be span, div or something else -->
    <i></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the `i` tag was a direct child I could apply styling in scss like this:

```
> i {
  color: grey
}
```

If I knew that the first child was always a div element i could apply styling like this:

```
> div > i {
  color: grey
}
```

However I don't know the type of the first child - it could be anything.

How do I correctly apply styling to the i tag in this case ?

- If it isn't possible with an dynamic solution - How can I then apply the styling to all the `i` tags within the root element, without styling `i` tags outside this element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying the root element and just leaving a space means descendant, so

```
.some-class i {
    color: grey;
 }
```

should do what you want.

---

If you want to only style them if they are at least one level deeper than the root then use `*` which means any tag.

```
 .some-class * i {
    color: grey;
 }
```

---

Finally, if you want to target them at specifically the third level use

```
  .some-class > * > i {
    color: grey;
 }
```

Comment: `> * > i` is the best solution for me, accessing all i tags was my "plan b"

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
.some-class i {
//Your styles here
}
```